# Cannot resolve symbol 'Immutable'

Tags: java, concurrency, intellij-idea, annotations, immutability

I'm new to threading in java and now read the "java concurrency in practice". As you possibly understand I'm trying to do any examples but can't. when I'm trying to use `@Immutable` annotation IDE(Idea) underlines it red. 
What is the possible reason of this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that you do not have the correct jar in your classpath.

The maven artifact for this jar is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.jcip</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcip-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
<dependency>
```

If you do not have this jar in your classpath, you don't have the annotation.

Note however that this is superseded by JSR 305. There is also a Maven artifact for an implementation of that JSR:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

(side note: excellent choice of a read! This is one must-have book for all Java devs out there)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but idea says it has two variants. which to choose? btw: look at the word dependency in your answer

Answer (score 1):

Download the [jar file providing the jcip annotations](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/jcip/jcip-annotations/1.0/jcip-annotations-1.0.jar) and add it to the [module dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html).

Answer (score 1):

As far as working with that book's examples, so all those annotations, like @ThreadSafe, @Immutable/@Threadsafe, they all are just symbolic (though fge above is correct, you can use those jars as well, but from learning perspective, just ignore them)

So, simply ignore them. Anywhere, if you see @Immutable, it simply means that code written is IMMUTABLE, by the virtue of code implementation.

You don't need any jar at all. Just remove those annotations from your examples :)